# flash builder 4 problem with stylesheets for flex

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I recently upgraded to the latest version of flashbuilder. Imported my the project I was working on and now it is riddled with errors. The errors I am getting that I don't understand are that it no longer recognizes the mx namespacse, but now has an mx1 namespace.  AnThis is really frustrating since I was almost done iwth this project and now it seems like things have changed. What has changed in the new flashbuilder that would cause this?

Comment: Did you upgrade from FlexBuilder 3 to FlashBuilder 4?

Comment: just to clarify, in my components, flash builder is recognizing mx.. i.e. <mx:Component>. But in my css, the stylesheets don't recognize mx.. but mx1 (in the codehinting) wha?

Comment: yes, i upgraded from fb3 tofb4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must now use namespace references in css files with Flex 4.

Per the examples on Adobe's site...

```
<Style>
    @namespace "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
    @namespace cx "com.mycompany.*";

    Button { color: #990000; }
    cx|MyFancyButton { color: #000099; }
</Style>
```

Please read more about the new changes here http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/CSS+Namespaces+Support

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so apparently if I use the namespace "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo", it didn't work. But when I use "http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml", it works